# Android cant execute POST request after GET

Tags: android, post, get, internal-server-error

My problem is this: after the GET request authorization and save cookies trying to perform a POST request to add data, but the server responds with 500 code. What's funny, because if POST query string form in a browser, it is executed correctly. The code below.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(site + "/admin/users/login_do/?login=admin&password=demo");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(site + "/admin/news/add/5/item/do/");
httppost.addHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID="+cookies.get(0).getValue()+"; umicms_session="+cookies.get(1).getValue()+"; stat_id="+cookies.get(2).getValue());

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("active", "1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "test"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[new][anons]", "anno"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[new][content]", "cont"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[new][publish_time]", "1420202020"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
Log.d("my",String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
Log.d("my",String.valueOf(status.getReasonPhrase()));
```

I've tried to run POST using HttpURLConnection, but also received 500 response. 
Who can tell what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I Forgot to send csrf token with POST request and set Referer header

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("csrf", csrf));

httppost.addHeader("Referer", referlink);
```